# ld unrecognized emulation mode /tmp/ccK2pwtc.o on ubuntu

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

I'm using the following machine:

```
Linux version 5.4.0-42-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-038) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)) #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020
```

The program

```
int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

when compiled

```
gcc -Wl,-m main.c
```

returns

```
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognised emulation mode: /tmp/ccJI1LRo.o
Supported emulations: elf_x86_64 elf32_x86_64 elf_i386 elf_iamcu elf_l1om elf_k1om i386pep i386pe
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not sure where to start as to knowing why.

Also, gcc and ld versions:

```
> gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

> ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Wl,-m` argument specifies that gcc should pass the `-m` argument to the linker.

When the linker is called, the `-m` option is used, and it's followed by a intermediate object file that's been compiled (`/tmp/ccJI1LRo.o`), as opposed to a supported emulation, which leads to the error message you've encountered.

The linker's `-m` option requires an argument for specifying an emulation. The output in your question lists supported emulations.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. My apologies for taking so long to accept